# Unable to create proper size and aligned icons from fontcustom when manually creating SVG files from font awesome SVG file

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, svg, custom-font, font-awesome

I'm trying to extract SVG files from fontawesome's svg file (fontawesome-webfont.svg) so that I can use only specific fonts and create my own custom fonts using fontcustom. All this to decrease font file size since am not using all the 300 or so icons of fontawesome, but only a handful.

How can I extract SVG files for existing icon? I tried many combinations, one of which is this:

From font-awesome.min.css, I know that icon-calendar is:

```
.icon-calendar:before { content: "\f073"; }
```

Next, from fontawesome-webfont.svg, I copied the glyph code for icon-calendar starting with d=", and created a new SVG file (by prefixing path) calendar.svg to be used by fontcustom.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M128 -128h288v288h-288v-288zM480 -128h320v288h-320v-288zM128 224h288v320h-288v-320zM480 224h320v320h-320v-320zM128 608h288v288h-288v-288zM864 -128h320v288h-320v-288zM480 608h320v288h-320v-288zM1248 -128h288v288h-288v-288zM864 224h320v320h-320v-320z M512 1088v288q0 13 -9.5 22.5t-22.5 9.5h-64q-13 0 -22.5 -9.5t-9.5 -22.5v-288q0 -13 9.5 -22.5t22.5 -9.5h64q13 0 22.5 9.5t9.5 22.5zM1248 224h288v320h-288v-320zM864 608h320v288h-320v-288zM1248 608h288v288h-288v-288zM1280 1088v288q0 13 -9.5 22.5t-22.5 9.5h-64 q-13 0 -22.5 -9.5t-9.5 -22.5v-288q0 -13 9.5 -22.5t22.5 -9.5h64q13 0 22.5 9.5t9.5 22.5zM1664 1152v-1280q0 -52 -38 -90t-90 -38h-1408q-52 0 -90 38t-38 90v1280q0 52 38 90t90 38h128v96q0 66 47 113t113 47h64q66 0 113 -47t47 -113v-96h384v96q0 66 47 113t113 47 h64q66 0 113 -47t47 -113v-96h128q52 0 90 -38t38 -90z"
style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" />
</svg>
```

If I don't include style=fill line, then SVG won't render in a browser and hence, fontcustom will create a blank TTF file.

So far, so good. So am able to create a SVG file manually, and run the fontcustom script to generate fontcustom.css and other font files. However, there are multiple problems at this stage:

1. The size of the resulting icon is not the same as I would get using font awesome. It's quite bigger. This has to do something with specifying something in SVG which I'm missing. But I don't know where to copy it from at the first place!
2. Some of the icons are rotated. For example, icon for star is rotated slightly.

   .icon-star-empty:before { content: "\f006"; }

It has to be something with individual SVG files that am manually creating. What am I missing? Or there's something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in just using Font Awesome icons, the best way to do this is to use [icnfnt.com](http://icnfnt.com/). If you want to combine some of your own icons, the [IcoMoon app](http://icomoon.io/app/) should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks, that works! However, am still unable to understand why fontcustom is not working for me on Mac. But for now, I'll settle with icnfnt.com :)